# For a sequence A1, A2, A3, ..., An, .... which obeys the following rules: An+1 > An and AAn = 3n, why is it obvious that A1 cannot be 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For this problem:

> The sequence a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>, ... obeys the following rules for
>   all n ≥ 1:
>   a<sub>n+1</sub> > a<sub>n</sub>, and a<sub>a<sub>n</sub></sub>= 3n.
>   Also a<sub>n</sub>> 0

When trying to find a<sub>1</sub> the solution lets x = a<sub>1</sub> giving a<sub>x</sub> = 3, it then goes on to say that since a<sub>x</sub> > a<sub>x-1</sub> > ... > a<sub>1</sub> ≥ 1, x ≤ 3.

It then goes on to say that it is obvious x cannot be 1 therefore x must be 2. Embarassingly I just can't see why its obvious x cannot be 1. Could someone explain please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_1=1$ then we have $$a_1=a_{a_1}=3\cdot 1=3$$

A contradiction, since $1\ne 3$.

Comment: Oh wow thank you I don't know how I missed that